# Non-negativity properties of SDE with singular drift at zero (with Bessel process as special case)

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, stochastic-analysis, stochastic-differential-equations

Consider the following family of SDEs:
$$
dX_t = \frac{1}{X_t^p} dt + dW_t
$$
with $X_0 > 0$.
For $p=1$, this is the 3-dimensional Bessel process, which stays positive for all time almost-surely.

Does this remain true for other values of $p$?

I was thinking that we could use the scale functions on the open interval $I = (0, \infty)$ to try and get this answer.

When $p\not=1$, the scale function $s_p(x)$ can be computed as
$$
\begin{aligned}
s_p(x)
&= \int_c^x \exp\left( -\int_c^y 2 \frac{1}{z^p} dz \right) dy \\
&= \int_c^x \exp\left( \frac{2}{p-1} (y^{1-p} - c^{1-p}) \right) dy
\end{aligned}
$$

### p<1

When $p=\frac{1}{2}$, we get
$$
\begin{aligned}
s_{1/2}(x)
&= \int_c^x \exp\left( 4\sqrt{c}- 4\sqrt{y} \right) dy \\
&= \frac{1}{8}\Big(1 + 4\sqrt{c} - \exp(4\sqrt{c}-4\sqrt{x}) (1 + 4 \sqrt{x}) \Big)
\end{aligned}
$$
Since both $\lvert s_{1/2}(0) \rvert < \infty$ and $\lvert s_{1/2}(\infty)\rvert < \infty$, we conclude that the (nonzero) probability of hitting zero is
$$
\frac{s_{1/2}(\infty) - s_{1/2}(X_0)}{s_{1/2}(\infty) - s_{1/2}(0)} = \exp(-4\sqrt{x}) (1 + 4 \sqrt{x})
$$
For $p \in (0, 1)$ in general, Mathematica shows $s_p(0)$ and $s_p(\infty)$ are both finite, which means the same conclusion applies for all these $p$s?

### p>1

On the other hand, for $p=2$, we get? (using Mathematica)
$$
\begin{aligned}
s_{2}(x)
&= \int_c^x \exp\left( \frac{2}{y}-\frac{2}{c} \right) dy \\
&= e^{-2/c} \left( -c e^{2/c} + e^{2/x} x + 2 E_i(2/c) - 2 E_i(2/x) \right)
\end{aligned}
$$
where $E_i$ denotes the exponential integral. Plugging in $0$ and $\infty$ again gives
$$
\lvert s_2(0) \rvert = \infty, \quad \lvert s_2(\infty) \rvert = \infty
$$
which implies that $X_t$ almost surely never hits $0$ and never diverges. I'm guessing that the same conclusion also holds for all $p>1$, although I wasn't able to verify this using Mathematica.

Is this approach correct?

Comment: For p<1 and $c=0$, you get a finite scale function eg. I input $\int e^{x^{p}}$ in Wolfram-alpha to get it in terms of incomplete-Gamma function.

Comment: For $p>1$ and $c=0$, you actually get zero because $e^{-c^{1-p}}\to 0$.

Comment: @ThomasKojar can you elaborate more on what you mean?

Comment: I mean that I input the function $\int e^{-cx^{a}}dx$ in Wolfram alpha https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%5Cint+e%5E%7B-cx%5E%7Ba%7D%7Ddx

Comment: @ThomasKojar where does the $\int e^{-c x^a}$ come from?

Comment: from your formula $exp(-\frac{2}{1-p}y^{1-p})$.